# What are the consequences of not uri encoding non-ascii utf-8 in a url query string

Tags: url, urlencode

According to several Q&As on SO you're supposed to uri encode anything not ascii and of course several punctuation characters like `=` and `&` in query string values and keys.

And yet AFAIK not uri encoding works just fine.

Example:

[http://greggman.github.io/doodles/show-query.html?書類=四角形&色=紫&名前=田中](http://greggman.github.io/doodles/show-query.html?%E6%9B%B8%E9%A1%9E=%E5%9B%9B%E8%A7%92%E5%BD%A2&%E8%89%B2=%E7%B4%AB&%E5%90%8D%E5%89%8D=%E7%94%B0%E4%B8%AD)

works as far as I can tell

The reason I ask is I'm using query strings to do some very simple localization of diagrams. A typical interactive diagram might have 1-5 strings, someone localizing an article that uses the diagram can do something like

```
bla bla bla bla see the following diagram

<iframe src="diagram.html?caption=localized%20string"></iframe

in the diagram above bla bla bla ....
```

It's much easier for writers and editors to be able to create, edit and correct non-encoded urls

```
<iframe src="diagram.html?caption=図形の回転し方"></iframe>
```

is much easier than

```
<iframe src="diagram.html?caption=%E5%9B%B3%E5%BD%A2%E3%81%AE%E5%9B%9E%E8%BB%A2%E3%81%97%E6%96%B9"></iframe>
```

Regardless of any "*standards*", if there are no consequences I'd prefer to leave the URLs as un-encoded as possible to make them easier to edit. For example this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9416628/encode-uri-spaces-etc-without-encode-non-ascii-characters) says you should encode them but as far as I can tell the example above works in IE, Edge, Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera.

I get that I could convert them in some kind of build step. That's beside the point though. If there are no consequences of not encoding them then I will choose to not encode them.

Also, this isn't about interfacing with random other websites or servers. It's my website, my server. I don't care if so-and-so server doesn't handle this case. In fact for my purposes the query string is only used by the client.

Looking at the headers it appears all browsers encode it when making the request from the server so that's seems to suggest it's fine.

So what would be the consequences of not uri encoding non-ascii utf-8 in query string keys and values?

Comment: is that just until one of the bytes in a multibyte character is 38 ('&') and the parser blows up

Comment: That will never happen with utf-8

Comment: notice what happens if you right click on your link and do "copy link address" or equivalent. The browser is encoding for you.

Comment: Yes it is, that's irrelevant to the question

Comment: sigh...your wrong comment has been vote up by someone else that doesn't actually know what they're talking about. You do know what utf-8 was specifically designed so there would never be any clashes with ascii right? Every multibyte character has the high bit set so clashes can't happen. That's pretty much the #1 design goal of utf-8.

Comment: well, no it's not. HTTP protocol won't allow it. Browser is responsible so the answer is behavior will be browser specific.

Comment: that proves nothing. it just shows the browser you are using is url-encoding it before sending to server, as most do. It's broken in IE. If you can live with that, fine.

Comment: HTTP only allows USASCII on the request line.

Comment: It's not broken in IE. I just didn't make the page the prints the query string IE compatible. IE handled the URL just fine

Comment: So you're right that the browser is encoding it before sending, which just suggest I'm right, there are no consequences. It doesn't matter if I use un-encoded non-ascii utf-8 in my query strings. Works in Safari, IE, Edge, Chrome, & Firefox. Any browser this didn't work in would likely not be able to browse half of the internet

Answer (score -1):

Testing your link in different browsers should give you an answer.

The browser would be responsibly for encoding the URL, which most of them do. But, parsing the querystring in javascript proves problematic.

In Internet Explorer, the URL gets rewritten as:
http://greggman.github.io/doodles/show-query.html?%E6%9B%B8%E9%A1%9E=%E5%9B%9B%E8%A7%92%E5%BD%A2&%E8%89%B2=%E7%B4%AB&%E5%90%8D%E5%89%8D=%E7%94%B0%E4%B8%AD

and your javascript prints nothing visible.

In Chrome and Firefox, the URL is displayed with multibyte characters, and you can see the query variables.

In Edge, the URL displayed the same as IE, but the javascript works as in Chrome.

Have you also tested in Safari, Opera, etc?  Bottom line, it will be browser specific.

Comment: That ie re-wrote the URL is irrelevant. It works just fine in IE. The code I had for parsing the URL was written in ES6 which IE doesn't support because the question had nothing to do with that result. Just so you'd see I updated the site. Click the link above and you'll see the entire process worked just fine.